# Show that the distribution of $X$ is shifted exponential

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with common PDF $f(x\mid\theta)$ of the shifted exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$.
>   (a) Show that if $Z\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ and if $X = Z + \theta$ for some constant $\theta$, then the distribution of $X$ is a shifted exponential.

What I did was this:

$f(x\mid\theta) = f(z+\mid\theta)= e^{[-(z+\theta-\theta)]}= e^{-z}$. Since $X=Z+\theta$, this implies that $Z=X-\theta$. So, we have $e^{[-(x-\theta)]}$  which the shifted exponential since the support is the same also.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Why are you introducing the $X_i$? It seems that you never use them afterwards?

Comment: I didn't introduce this. It is in the question.

Comment: Yes, in the question that you posted. If this is not your own question and you copied it from another source, you should state that and state the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X>t) &= \mathbb P(Z+\theta>t)\\
&= \mathbb P(Z>t-\theta)\\
&=e^{-(t-\theta)}\mathsf1_{\{t>\theta\}},
\end{align}
so that $X$ has a shifted exponential distribution. Note that the inclusion of the indicator $\mathsf 1_{\{t>\theta\}}$ is essential, as otherwise we would have $\mathbb P(X>t)>1$ for $t<\theta$, which is not possible for a probability distribution.